# pandas groupby first column shifted down

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So I have read in a csv file as a pandas dataframe:

[image]

But when I group it, the year column is shifted down by one:

[image]

So when I try to pull out Years into a numpy array, it gives an error saying `"KeyError:'Year'"`.

Is there a way to get the array to find the years, or a way to shift that first column up by one?

I have found a way to shift a dataframe column up by one, but I need to shift the grouping, not the dataframe.

I also tried turning the new grouping into a new dataframe so that I can shift the year column up, but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Year is the name of the index.

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: df.index.name = "foo"

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
     A  B
foo
0    1  2
1    3  4
```

Pull out the index with .index:

```
In [15]: df.index
Out[15]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64', name='foo')

In [16]: df.index.values
Out[16]: array([0, 1])
```